# Ordering checks for my LLC

Tags: check

I'm ordering checks for my newly formed LLC.  I wondered if I should put my personal name on the checks, just the LLC name or both.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I have an LLC for a rental property. I didn't put my name on the checks, and I use an office address for the LLC. I was trying to have some level of privacy, and a management company insulating me from direct dealings with tenants.

If your intent is privacy, I'd avoid printing the name.

Answer (score 2):

If you want people making the checks out to the LLC, I'd suggest putting only the LLC's name on the check. Don't distract the customers unnecessarily.